# Security issues with mobile app

Tags: php, android, json, security, ssl

We are developing a mobile app for a client.  We would like to get some suggestions on how to secure the communication between the app and the website. We are building native iOS & Android apps. The website is developed in PHP, and we plan to use Json. We want to make sure no other application is going to access the Json services. We plan to encrypt the query strings for the JSon service and pass some access tokens. Do you suggest some extra security features that you might have used in previous projects? Also point us to some links which might explain in more details. We were considering making it mandatory to call the services over SSL but not sure of the overhead on the server, has anyone experienced performance issues with SSL before with a similar architecture?

Comment: Mobile security is kind of broad and a bit off topic for Stack Overflow (unless you have a specific question). I believe [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) allows design questions. You might try there if the question is closed. One thing I will recommend: avoid that damn web app/browser security model and pin the server's certificate or public key. You already know who you should be connecting to, so leverage that knowledge. OWASP has an example at [Certificate and Public Key Pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning).

Comment: @jww note that if a question is closed on Stack Overflow as too broad, it will likely be closed for the same reason if it is reposted without taking the reason for the closure into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your mobile app authenticate into your API.  There is a few ways you could go about it, using Basic authorization, OAuth 1.0a, or even OAuth 2 (client-credentials flow).  This will allow you to have your mobile app to have the credentials to your REST service, but no one else.  Using HTTPS will combat man-in-the-middle attacks but does come with some overhead.  Comparing HTTP vs HTTPS, HTTP will always be faster but I highly recommend HTTPS.

I think you can find a lot of good pointers in this post:

https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way/

and this slideshare:

http://www.slideshare.net/stormpath/secure-your-rest-api-the-right-way